# Preventing Ember Data Caching & loading model data on demand

Tags: ember.js

We are considering moving from Backbone to Ember.  There are a few issues through I can't get answers to from the docs.

1) Ember-Data caches it's data.  Our application is multi-user so other users need to be able to see new records created by everyone.  Is there a way around this?  I read on another post that when a query string is passed, ember data does not cache data, is this true? If it is, can I then just always send query string and nothing will be cached?

2) Ember data has a single model in the router that appears to be instantiated at route load time.  I can see that your can request data from multiple sources by returning an object with many this.store.find calls.  Say I have a select element and when you select an option, another select gets populated with items based on the first select (which requires a call back to the server).  How would that work, how can I get model data on demand (not at route load time)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it answers your question but you can always call

```
model.reload()
```

to refetch data from server so you can work with up to date data.

Comment: So will that update all models currently in ember-data?  Would I need to call this at the start of each route?

Comment: it will update the specific model initially instantiated in your route

Comment: I suppose a negative of this is that how would I know that the record was retrieved from cache.  If not I would do 2 calls to the server.

Comment: Well you can't really bypass the store (ember-data wouldn't be very useful otherwise) so without asking the server for information about the state of your model (is it up to date or not) I don't think you can "guess" if the record has been updated by someone else. If you don't want to use a store maybe ember-data is not what you are looking for and you would be better off using simple jquery ajax calls.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider Faye (http://faye.jcoglan.com/), which would let you have a pub/sub setup that could update your store by listening to topics of interest.  This uses WebSocket for the streaming interface.  You could then put new objects into the store, remove or update existing objects which the server could publish to the client.